# Non-static method constants::getActivationList() should not be called statically

Tags: php, methods, non-static

I'm using a2billing application, integrated to Asterisk.
When trying to add a DID through the Admin web interface, I get an error message on the page:
"Your new did hasn't been inserted."

In the httpd/error_log it's stated:
PHP Strict Standards:  Non-static method constants::getActivationList() should not be called statically in /var/www/html/a2billing/admin/Public/form_data/FG_var_did.inc on line 52, , referer: http://XXXXXXXXXXX/a2billing/admin/Public/A2B_entity_did.php?form_action=ask-add&section=8

The code on line 52 of that file "FG_var_did.inc":
$actived_list = Constants::getActivationList();

The PHP version I'm using is:
PHP 5.4.16 (cli) (built: Nov  6 2016 00:29:02)
Copyright (c) 1997-2013 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v2.4.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2013 Zend Technologies

I've already disabled "~E_STRICT" in php.ini.

Anyone got any ideas how to resolve this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

I have no idea about the application you are using, but if the method is not static, you should first initialize the object and call the method :

```
$var = new ClassNmae();
$var->method();
```

instead of `ClassNmae::method()`

Or in short you can use as `(new ClassName)->method();`

Comment: Thanks for looking into this. I was hoping to fix it with a PHP config setting, I prefer not to touch the code, as I expect there are more methods being called statically elsewhere in the source.